# Doesnt the fact that cash reserves go down in recessions contradict Keynesianism?

Tags: new-keynesian-economics

[image: Cash]

It seems cash reserve is procyclical. Also anyone have the financial cash reserve data?

Comment: Could you explain how this contradicts Keynesianism (IE. provide the relevant equations)? Money supply (M2) goes down during recessions due to loans going bad. This is not something that is even part of the classic Keynsian theory AFAIRC.

Answer (score -1):

You very often see Krugman an other economists imply that corporations holding cash is a bad thing or affects demand.

http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/07/02/cash-is-not-the-problem/?_r=0

However, you have to remember that Krugman is just stating his personal opinion. He does sometimes say things that contradict academic Keynesianism.

The fact that corporations hoard less cash during recessions doesn't necessarily contradict Keynesianism or New Keynesianism, but it does require these theories to explain why corporations behave this way (which the theorists have not attempted).

Comment: -1 for the *ad hominem* paragraph, the point (last paragraph) can be driven home without it

Comment: Then answer is "no" as stated in the last paragraph.